# Extension from an equality of two events to many more events

Tags: probability

How can I extend/generalise the following equality of two events

**P**{$A_1 \cup A_2$} = **P**{$A_1$} + **P**{$A_2$} - **P**{$A_1A_2$}

to many more events. Would this be correct?

**P**{$A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ...A_n$} = **P**{$A_1$} + **P**{$A_2$} + ... **P**{$A_n$} - **P**{$A_1A_2$} - ...**P**{$A_{n-1}A_n$}

Thank you.

Comment: This is related to the inclusion-exclusion principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability

Comment: $$\mathbb P(A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_n)=\mathbb P(A_1\cup \underbrace{\{A_2\cup \cdots \cup A_n\}}_{A_2^\prime})$$

Comment: One of the easiest ways to *see* the extension (and to write it correctly) is to re-express these relationships in terms of the indicator functions.  The first equality is equivalent to $1-(1-I_A)(1-I_B)=I_A+I_B-I_AI_B,$ easily proven using the distributive, associative, and commutative laws of algebra.  The general relation expands the product $1 - \prod_{j=1}^n(1-I_{A_j})$ into a linear combination of monomials and can be rigorously proven using mathematical induction.

Comment: Thank you all for guiding me to new concepts. @whuber, that was a very neat method to extend the equality to more than two events, but how could I relate **P** {$A_1 \cup A_2$} to $1 - (1 - I_A)(1 - I_B)$?

Comment: The indicator of an intersection is the product of indicators: $I_{A\cap B}=I_A\,I_B.$ The indicator of a complement is the complement of the indicator: $I_{U\setminus A} = 1 - I_A.$ Apply these observations to $A\cup B=(U\setminus A)\cap(U\setminus B)$ where $U=A\cup B.$

Comment: Thanks, @whuber. Just to clarify, did you mean $A \cup B = 1 - (U$ \ $A) \cap (U$ \ $B)$ instead of $A \cup B = (U$ \ $A) \cap (U$ \ $B)$?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I would have written $A\cup B=U\setminus\left[(U\setminus A)\cap(U\setminus B)\right].$  Thanks for catching that.